# find the radius of a circle passing through the vertices of a noncircular quadrilateral,

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

know that the radical axis of two circles is the best alternative line to the line connecting the intersection points of two non-intersecting circles

in the same way I'm trying to find the best alternative circle for the circle passing through the vertices of a noncircular quadrilateral

I'm looking for an actual geometric alternative that has common theorems with the circle passing through the vertices of a ring quadrilateral, so I'm not looking for naïve answers like the smallest possible circle with the four points inside it or the largest possible circle that makes the four points outside it or other answers like that

Two days ago, I met a theorem that brought me closer to reaching the answer I am looking for, as the theorem helps to find the right point to be the center of that circle we are looking for

[image]

If $ABCD$ quadrilateral circular, $AB, CD$ They intersect in $M$ and $BC, AD$ They intersect in $N$ and $AC, BD$ They intersect in $P$, the point of convergence of heights in the triangle $MNP$ is the center of the circle passing through the vertices of the quadrilateral $ABCD$.

This theorem is known as the Brookard theorem and obviously its idea can be applied for any quadrilateral, even if it's not a circular quadrilateral, so I think I found the center of the circle I'm looking for.

But I haven't found any theorem that indicates the radius, is there anyone who can find the radius of this circle?

And I'd be happy if someone could find more common properties between the prospective circle and the circle in the case of a circular quadrilateral.

I hope my question is clear

Comment: I want to link this question to a related question that I asked a long time ago but I don't know how to do it, this is the link to the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729591/a-large-reference-or-list-of-examples-of-euclidean-geometry-and-imaginary-states

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the Wikipedia page about the circular quadrilateral, it was found that it was possible to derive a formula suitable for the radius from the Bramisvara formula

$R=\frac{\sqrt{(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+bc)}}{4K}$

so that $K$ refers to the area of the quadrilateral $ABCD$